How to setup cucumber in vue to test the navigation function via BDD
I’m trying to test navigation in a Vue.js application using Cucumber.js. I want to simulate clicking a link on the home page and verify that it navigates to the about page. It seems that this brings up a few problems, such as the Vue tag syntax. Is there a best practice way to solve this problem?
Here is the relevant code:
navigationStep.ts
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import { Given, When, Then } from '@cucumber/cucumber'
import App from '../../../src/App.vue'
import router from '../../../src/router/index.ts'
import assert from 'assert'

let wrapper

Given('I am at the home page', function () {
  this.wrapper = mount(App, {
    global: {
      plugins: [router]
    }
  })
  router.push('/')
})

When('I click at the link', function () {
  const aboutLink = this.wrapper.get('a[href="/about"]')
  aboutLink.trigger('click')
})

Then('I should be at the second page', function () {
  const currentRoute = router.currentRoute.value.path
  assert.strictEqual(currentRoute, '/about')
})

App.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterLink, RouterView } from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
</script>

<template>
  <header>
    <img alt="Vue logo" class="logo" src="@/assets/logo.svg" width="125" height="125" />

    <div class="wrapper">
      <HelloWorld msg="You did it!" />

      <nav>
        <RouterLink to="/">Home</RouterLink>
        <RouterLink to="/about">About</RouterLink>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <RouterView />
</template>

This is the error message I got:
<script setup lang="ts">


SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\PatrickSchwendemann\Documents\Git\vue-project-basic\__tests__\bdd\steps\navigationStep.ts:3:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...


Thank you for your help

This is about test runner, not test framework. It's unknown how you run tests but this should involve the transpilation of .vue files. This can be naturally done in Jest, etc via plugins
